# incorporating error in best fit line equation

Tags: error, error-propagation

I have two sets of data {X} and {Y} each element in those two sets has its own unique +/- error. I graphed x vs y in a scatter plot along with every point's error bar (both in x and y (x1 +/- a1 , y1 +/- b1)) and added a best fit line. the best fit line is linear and therefore has an equation of the form mx+b. My question is how do I calculate the error in the constants of the equation y=mx+b.
edit: the elements of each set contain unique uncertainty in both sides for example its x1=10+0.5 or x1=10-0.25 and not x1=+/-0.5. similarly with Y.

update:
Eiso
(10^52 erg s−1)
35.00 ± 7,
1.70 ± 0.9,
114.00 ± 9,
14.10 ± 2.8,
24.00 ± 2,
188.00 ± 10
. Epeak
(KeV)
464.10 ± 26,
26.01 ± 2,
1333.53 ± 28,
816.62 ± 88,
1125.98 ± 48,
1090.06 ± 54.

A sample of the actual data, keep in mind that these errors will be transformed in the log space. so the plotted data will actually be
y points = Log(Eiso) and the x points = log (Epeak/avg(Epeak)) which changes the error. Then a best fit line would be calculated and my main concern is with the error in the constants of y=mx+b.

Comment: It depends on how you compute your "best fit line".

Comment: Used excel to compute it and it doesn't add the error to the equation

Comment: Least square method

Comment: If you are willing to ignore the error in $x$, you could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Uncertainty_quantification

Comment: I don't think its possible for me to ignore the error in x

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. Can you show with an example exactly what data you have for each data point and say what assumptions you are willing to make about these errors.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  The following link is step-by-step through bkm for linear fits using the R software tool.  Personally I use R in the RStudio IDE, which are both free.  It is a solid data-analysis tool.  Link: https://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/linear-regression-in-r/

Comment: I updated the problem and included the actual data. When it comes to the assumptions about the errors I'm not exactly sure since in both X and Y there are data points with high errors.

Comment: It would be nice to know what the errors *mean* and how they are determined.

Comment: The errors are the accumulation of instrumental errors in observation. These are all mainly observational errors

Comment: How do you measure or estimate them?  This matters because it affects how one might analyze the situation and develop a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf X := (x_1, \ldots x_n)^t$ be the column vector containing all your $x$ values, similarly $\mathbf Y := (y_1,\ldots,y_n)^t$, and finally let $\beta := (m, b)^t$.

The least-squares (LS) method computes your values $m$ and $b$ as follows: Create the design matrix $\mathbf X_d$:
$$
\mathbf X_d := \left(\begin{matrix}
                      x_1 & 1 \\
                      x_2 & 1 \\
                      \vdots & \vdots \\
                      x_n & 1 \\
                     \end{matrix}\right).
$$
Then, our goal can be expressed as trying to find the solution $\beta$ for the equation:
$$
\mathbf X_d \beta = \mathbf Y.
$$
Next, LS computes the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) (MPPI) $\mathbf X_d^+$ of $\mathbf X_d$, defined as:
$$
\mathbf X^+ := (X_d^t X_d)^{-1} X_d^t
$$
(where we presume that $(X_d^t X_d)^{-1}$ has full rank, i.e. the $x_i$ are not all the same). Then, $\beta$ is obtained as:
$$
\beta = \mathbf X^+ \mathbf Y.
$$

So this is the very formula that LS uses to compute the coefficients $\beta = (m, b)^t$ from your data. I tell you all this, because, if you presume nonnegligible errors in your data $\mathbf X$, you would have to compute the condition number of $\mathbf X_d$:
$$
cond(\mathbf X_d) := \|\mathbf X_d\| \|\mathbf X_d^+\|.
$$
If this number is large, **your [LS is ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Condition_number) and not reliable. I.e. the error propagated from your $\mathbf X$ to your solution vector $\beta$ could blow up**.

Now, presume that the condition number is small and LS can be used. Then, to actually get some error bars for $\beta$ you could apply methods of [error propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty), to see how the errors are amplified by the application of the MPPI.

A more general approach, that can also be used if the formulae are not as simple as for LS, is the application of the [bootstrap method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)). Bootstrap computes, for a given sample, approximations of complex statistics. And the variance of your vector $\beta$ is such a statistic. Python provides a ready to use [implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bootstrap.html), and for comprehensive R packages see e.g. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/index.html) or [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootstrap/index.html).

---

Edit: As @whuber points out in the comments, there is another problem with errors in the explanatory $\mathbf X$ data: If the error of the $x$ values is comparable with the overall standard deviation of the $x$, then one could get a reduced slope estimate.

Comment: This answer does not address the unique and difficult part of the problem setting, which is that the *explanatory (x) variable is also measured with appreciable error.* Your approach yields biased estimates in that situation.  Propagating the error will not remove that bias.

Comment: @whuber Could you explain this a little more? I thought that I do address the situation where both $x$ and $y$ have error.

Comment: See our posts that refer to "errors in variables" regression.  This is a subtle but important issue.  Intuitively, when the $x_i$ are measured with appreciable error (which means the variance is a sizable proportion of the overall variance of the $x_i$), the resulting horizontal "smearing" of the data tends to have a kind of regularizing effect to reduce the magnitude of the slope estimate.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I believe a bootstrap *appropriately carried out* might be able to identify and compensate for this bias.   The details matter!

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with more info.